# Field homomorphism respects arbitrary arithmetic expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory

A field homomorphism $f:A \to B$ respects the fields' binary operations, in the sense that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.

When you have an explicit expression like $expr = x^3 + 15x - 32/y$, it's easy to verify using the normal order of operations that the $f(expr) = f(x)^3 + 15f(x) - 32/f(y)$.

But how would you go about showing that $f$ respects arbitrary finite sequences of well-formed arithmetic operations, for example $f(a_1 S_1 a_2 S_2 a_3 S_3 a_4 S_4 \cdots S_{n-1} a_n )$, where each $a_k$ is a field element and $S_k$ is one of the field's binary or unary operations, or a parenthesis.

I've sort of taken this for granted for years.

Could you use induction on the number of symbols, or operations?

Or is there a much easier way?

Comment: Induction on the number of operations. Take the 'last' operation you need to perform to compute the expression inside $f$ and commute $f$ with it. By induction $f$ commutes with what remains inside it because it uses a smaller number of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of the expression as a string of symbols. Instead, think of the expression as a finite composition of functions representing the binary and unary operations in the field. The string version of the expression is just convenient shorthand.

Now use induction on the number of function calls/operations, like [Franklin.vp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26489/franklin-vp) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider each expression with different operations and parentheses as a (binary) tree with field elements at the leaves and operators at the other nodes. Build the same tree, but with the leaves $x$ replaced with $f(x)$. Then for all nodes (with value $x$, say) the corresponding image node has vallue $f(x)$:
Proceed from the leaves to the root (which is essentially induction by the number of nodes in possible trees): If the children of a node with operator $\circ$ have values $a,b$, then the image node has children $f(a),f(b)$ and we find from $f(a\circ b)=f(a)\circ f(b)$ that the image parent node has just the value we expected.